# Java - Linked Lists

Tags: java

I'm a Java novice trying to get a set of activities, with start and end times, into a linked list and then optimize the schedule for the room these activities will take place in.  I have the linked list created and it seems I have succeeded to pass it into my maxRoomUse method where I will do the schedule.  I am having trouble understanding how to iterate through my list in the maxRoomUse method.  I am not allowed to import any packages to help me.

Comment: Why you just do not add a getter to your list member and iterate it where need it ? you could also implement an iterator for this job

Comment: You already iterate through the list in its add() and its toString() methods. What's the problem?

Comment: Is this an assignment or homework? What have you tried so far to iterate through the list?

Comment: What is an ActivityList?

Comment: This is homework.  Linked Lists were not taught to us - we were given an example and asked to step through it to understand it.  That got me to this point but now, I'm stuck.  I was able to take care of the schedule in the ActivityList class because "list", "current", and ".next" are all inherent to it.  Now that I have to do the iteration in a different method, I'm lost.  For example, myStuffToDo.next doesn't seem to have any meaning in the maxRoomUse method.  Why?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am also not understanding how I could implement a getter since each node contains String and int.  What is the return type?

Comment: JB Nizet - The problem is I've been staring at this for hours and I'm still lost.

Comment: I figured out to pass a node into my method, not the entire list.  Right or wrong, it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a nested iterator class inside List class.

ListIterator implements Iterator, and which has 3 methods.

The implementation is like this.

```
    public boolean next() {
        return current == null;
    }

    public Activity next(){
        if (! this.hasNext())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        //if (this.curModCount != modCount)
        //    throw new ConcurrentModificationException()
        Activity data = this.current.activity;
        this.current = this.current.next();
        return data;
    }

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```